# MS Word 2013 variant does not reference an automation object

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I have just upgraded from office to office 2013. One of my apps uses MSWord automation to convert word to pdf.

The following code worked ok for Word 2007 and 2010, but not I keep getting the above OLEError at the call to MSApp.Documents.open. The code is below. Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong? I have also tried stripping out all params to the call to open other than the filename, but this still falls down with the above exception

```
Function convertToPDF(filename:string);
var MSApp, doc:variant;
begin
MSApp := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
    try
      MSApp.visible:=false;

      MSApp:=MSApp.version;
      version:=trunc(strToFloat(MSApp));

      if version>11 
    then begin //should be greater than word 2003 so should have capability of printing to pdf
              Doc:=MSApp.Documents.Open(fileName, false, true, false);
              MSApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(outputfile, wdFormatPDF, emptyParam, emptyparam, false);
            end;
finally
    varclar(doc);
    msApp.quit;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure this ever worked?  I'm pretty sure it didn't.   Either that or your real code is not the code you've shown above.  This seems highly suspect : `MSApp:=MSApp.version;`  You're overwriting your Word object with its version number...

Comment: The code you posted has never worked in any Delphi version, because it's totally incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but please ready my comment below. I explained this.

Answer (score -2):

You should use saveas2 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836084%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Saveas is no more part of the object model.

Comment: Thanks. I did some tidy up to my code which seems to have gone badly wrong. It was the assignment of version to msApp which was causing the problem. Not sure how that got there. Corrected now and works fine.